# difference between ckeditor entermode div and entermode p

Tags: html, ckeditor, carriage-return

I noticed that CkEditor has problems with using entermode br (mainly slowness after typing text for a long time).

So I'm looking into the other entermodes (p and div).

I see that entermode p is adviced by CkEditor.

However, this introduces margins below the content, which is not desired (as the users are not used to typing paragraphs).

So, I was thinking of using entermode div , which seems more correct in this case.

However, I want to avoid introducing problems by using entermode div.

Are there known differences in behaviour between entermode p and entermode div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [`CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss`](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.contentsCss) option to avoid unexpected margins, paddings and other browser default css rules. Now you can make `<p>` to look like `<br />`.

Comment: Thanks , that works inside the editor.

However , it doesn't work outside the editor : it means i have to change the style of p everywhere i want to show the content created by the editor.

Comment: The problem is that this content may be used inside emails , and the recipients won't have this style set , so they will receive it with margins.

Comment: @Kenny you can send inline css in email :)